# Multivariable calculus limit proof

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I came across with this statement and I can't neither prove it right nor find a counterexample. The statement is:

Consider two functions $F(x,y)$ and $G(x,y)$ continuous and differentiable around a point $(a,b)$. If the limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}\frac{F(x,y)}{G(x,y)}$$
is of the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ and
$$\left[\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}\right]_{(a,b)}\neq0$$
Then the previous limit does not exist.

I've tried several examples and it seems to work. Any hint will be extremely appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the map $(F,G):U\to{\mathbb R}^2$ defined in an open nbhd of $(a,b)$. The condition on the partial derivatives says that the jacobian determinant of $(F,G)$ doesn't vanish at $(a,b)$, hence it is a diffeo near $(a,b)$ (and maps $(a,b)$ to $(0,0)$). Thus we can consider the change of variables $u=F(x,y),\ v=G(x,y)$, and the limit becomes 
$$
\lim_{(u,v)\to(0,0)}\frac{u}{v},
$$
which clearly doesn't exists. Only one bug here, to apply the local inversion theorem one needs not just differentiability around the point, but class 1, or at least non-zero jacobian determinant in a nbhd of the point (not only at the point, this refinement is not easy). Thus the hypothesis must be refined accordingly.